# Adding PyMongo to Python IDE

Tags: python, ide, pymongo

I am a python newbie - I want to use the pymongo library to access mongoDb using some convenient IDE, and after looking through the web i decided to use WING.

Can some one point how to add the pymongo library to the WING ide (or to any other IDE for that matter)? i want to get the auto-completion for commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can consider using Sublime text. You can run your python programs straight from your editor. It has autocompletion (suggest a listing for what you might have meant to type in). Though it won't suggest function names as in Netbeans or eclipse. But still its a very elegant editor used by many. Also you can [install pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html) as suggested in the link. If you don't have pip, [follow these steps](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)

Comment: That's not entirely true, though in the development stage, https://github.com/svaiter/SublimeJEDI provides already a good completion for Sublime. (using the jedi library)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows platform just install the pymongo.exe file and it will install in python directory. Then you will be able to access it in any IDE such PyCharm by typing:

import pymongo